# Querying Analysis Server with MDX from Excel using MSOLAP returns different results than from SSMS

Tags: excel, ssms, mdx, olap-cube

So. I have prepared an MDX query in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which shows me the result that I want. However, I would like to query it from Excel instead of from SSMS, so that I can work with the figures and create graphs and such.

My MDX could look like the following:

> SELECT 
>         [Dates].[By Month].[Month].&[2015-02]
>         ON 0, 
>         (
>         [Region-Office].[Region Hierarchy].AllMembers *
>         [Measures].[Earnings]
>         ) ON 1
>
> FROM [Model]

When querying this MDX in SSMS, I get the result that I want: namely that both Region and Office is printed **to only one column**:

[Above MDX query returned from SSMS, note that both region and office is in the same column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkKxl.png)

When I turn to Excel and create an MSOLAP.6 connection with the following connection string:

> Provider=MSOLAP.6;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=CubeData;Data Source=CubeServer;Extended Properties="VisualMode=2";MDX Compatibility=2;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error

I get a different result: namely that **region is printed to one separate column and office printed to another separate column**:

[Above MDX query returned to Excel table using MSOLAP.6, note that region and office is printed in two separate columns, which is not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QOUa.png)

Can I in any way control what the Excel table returns so that I can retrieve the same output as the one I query in SSMS?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: it is putting each level in a different column? This is via a pivot table with a link to your cube? i.e. no custom sets created in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

The connection string you supplied is the same as I have when using excel's out-of-the-box SSAS connection wizard to a pivot table, so I'll assume nothing more complicated than that.

If in a pivot I add a multi-level dimension to rows I get behaviour like the following - for a "classic" pivot:

[image]

I can create a custom set in Excel like the following:

[image]

That set then becomes available to use and all members are in a single column:

[image]